# How to view/edit/cancel scheduled transactions on Parity wallet?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I've set up a scheduled (after a specific time) transaction using Parity wallet and the transaction is not showing up in the Transactions view. Just wondering if there is a way to view/cancel/modify scheduled transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open APPLICATIONS and find the TX QUEUE VIEWER dapp.

[image: dapplications]

It will allow you to review your pending transactions and resubmit (overwrite them).

[image: tx queue]

Note, cancelling is a feature only available on the future releases of 1.7.x branch.

If you want to cancel a scheduled transaction with earlier releases, just stop parity and run it without persistent transaction queue:

```
parity --no-persistent-txqueue
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm on 1.7 parity and I don't see a way to kill them...where are they stored locally?

Comment: Downvoted as Parity 1.7.x doesn't appear to have a cancel option.  Please correct the answer or provide more clear instructions on how to cancel.

Comment: agree..i also don't see this option. downvoted

Comment: How do you run parity on the command line?  I have parity installed but i'm getting "bash: parity: command not found"

Comment: @LampShade which version? which operating system? how did you install parity?

Comment: @5chdn macOS Sierra.  I tried installing via brew, didn't work.  So I installed the macOS version from: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases  Recently made this SO post about the issue: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27606/parity-cli-bash-parity-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

The option listed above, of restarting without persistent transaction queue still works as of 1.7.6

parity --no-persistent-txqueue

Also, under 'Signer' on the top menu bar, you should be able to view scheduled transactions and edit/cancel them.