# parity CLI "bash: parity: command not found"

Tags: parity, mac-osx, parity-signer

How do I run the parity CLI?  I installed it from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases) but running parity on the command line results in "bash: parity: command not found"

I'm trying to cancel pending transactions in parity during this crazy network congestion with the help of "parity --no-persistent-txqueue"

I installed via the wizard.  Not sure what location it installed to.  I also tried via [brew based on their docs](https://github.com/paritytech/homebrew-paritytech/blob/master/README.md) but brew can't seem to find parity.

```
Pako-2:~ pako$ brew install parity
Error: No available formula with the name "parity" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
==> You haven't updated Homebrew in a while.
A formula for parity might have been added recently.
Run `brew update` to get the latest Homebrew updates!
Pako-2:~ pako$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
Pako-2:~ pako$ brew install parity
Error: No available formula with the name "parity" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
==> You haven't updated Homebrew in a while.
A formula for parity might have been added recently.
Run `brew update` to get the latest Homebrew updates!
Pako-2:~ pako$ brew install parity --stable
Error: No available formula with the name "parity" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
==> You haven't updated Homebrew in a while.
A formula for parity might have been added recently.
Run `brew update` to get the latest Homebrew updates!
Pako-2:~ pako$
```

Comment: Which OS have you installed on? Have you tried running parity from the location at where it is installed?

Comment: Mac.  The install wizard doesn't show me where it installs to.  So I'm not sure where to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tap first :)

```
brew tap paritytech/paritytech
brew install parity
```

Comment: Not sure how i messed the tap part up.  That did it!